# Ubuntu 11.10 network speed

Tags: 11.10, networking, performance

Just upgraded to 11.10 from 11.04 . My internet speed is VERY slow now. I did a speed test with two similar laptops. The one running windows has a download speed of 14Mb/s while the one running Ubuntu does not exceed .09 Mb/s (on the same network).

I never had an issue with 11.04.... Help

Comment: A lot more information is needed in order to help you. hardware info at least.

Comment: Show us the output of `ifconfig -a`, and tell us what you're connected to. If your MTU is too large, you could be sending 2 packets for every 1 you think you're sending. Please describe the "speedtest" and your network configuration.

Comment: Subjectively, I can feel web sites loading slightly slower in XUbuntu 11.10 than in Windows XP (using the same browser version and the same browser extensions set) at the same time as the general system UI seems to be notably faster (more responsive) than in Windows.

Comment: +1 to this question as I have similar problem with 11.10 x86 - wifi performance degrades considerably from 20Mb/s down to 1-2Mb/s - to provoke degradation it is enough to watch some youtube video, and performance will not be restored afterwards.

Comment: Follow-up: switching Wifi off and on - restores original performance to expected level; problem seems to be quite reproducible

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. :)

Answer (score 3):

Look under connection information for the connection you use to access the net. If the driver is r8169 and you have a Realtek RTL8111 network chip on your motherboard then follow [this post](http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=49&t=80757) to get the correct driver installed. Ubuntu 11.10 uses kernel version 3.x so take the necessary steps noted for this kernel version (I didn't modify the makefile, just copied the files as instructed instead).

To find out what network chip you have try running `lspci` to list devices on your PCI bus. The culprit was

```
05:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168B PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet controller (rev 06)
```

Before doing this my internet connection was inconsistent, slow and would drop a lot of packets (as shown by running `ifconfig`). Now its running fast with no dropped packets.

Point taken about my post being "forum like" in the comment, I have amended this answer to reflect that.

Comment: hi @mark jones. this is not a forum. this is a question and answer site! please do not ask questions as answers. add a comment to the existing question instead or ask your own.

Comment: My feeling is that this isn't a DNS server problem as that shouldn't affect a download speed test result.

Comment: After updating the kernel from version 3.0.0-12 to 3.0.0-13 I needed to run through this process again as it installed the r8169 driver again.

Comment: The Realtek driver no longer has the update problem where the user needs to copy files manually. This still happens to me on every kernel update (latest as of now is 3.0.0.16) so I can't understand why this question has been closed as being it's deemed too localised.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution [here](http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=49&t=80757).

"*The Realtek r8168B network card does not work out of the box in Redhat, Centos, Fedora, or Ubuntu: instead of loading the r8168 driver, modprobe loads the r8169 driver, which is broken as can be seen with ifconfig which shows large amounts of dropped packets.*"

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and it seems that

> when you're on batterie Ubuntu reduces the power given to the WiFi
>   radio to save it

as said [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/67587/my-wifi-in-ubuntu-11-10-so-slow) by [@Bilal Akhtar](https://askubuntu.com/users/629/bilal-akhtar)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe is a DNS problem:

I'll show you how to use [Google Public DNS](http://code.google.com/intl/es-ES/speed/public-dns/).

1) <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and paste `gksu gedit /etc/resolv.conf`

2) Copy and paste the following lines:

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

3) Restart your computer and that's all.

---

*You also may try [Open DNS](http://www.opendns.com/) if Google DNS doesn't work*

```
nameserver 208.67.222.222 
nameserver 208.67.220.220
```

Answer (score 0):

I have this problem with 64bit 11.10 and I have an NVidia ethernet.  It seems to be global to 11.10.  I also noted that when I type 'ifconfig' it shows an ip6 address when I configured my network without one.  Somehow the ip6 may be part of the problem.

The other problem I found is the default gateway.  If the ip address is not in /etc/hosts (with a name) then this will slow things down considerably as well.

All I added to /etc/hosts is

192.168.1.1 router # default network router

Removing the IP6 support in FireFox does help a lot as well.

Hope someone comes up with a fix.  Hopefully it will include scrapping Unity. ;)