# My wifi in ubuntu 11.10 so slow

Tags: 11.10, wireless

how could I repair?
I update Ubuntu 11.04 to ubuntu 11.10, Im new user, help me 
Thanks

Comment: Your question is too vague right now, what’s your network card model?

Comment: @Juan Please add more details to your question. Once you have edited your question to include things like: the type of wireless card, the speeds you're getting, the speeds you anticipate, any errors you've received, or any other details pertinent to this question. Then flag the question or reply to this comment and it'll be reviewed for reopening!

Answer (score 5):

Since your description isn't very clear, this solution might or might not work.

On laptops, when on battery Ubuntu reduces the power given to the WiFi radio to save battery. There's a way to force Ubuntu to not make this change and instead give full power to the radio. To do this, run these command **while** on battery:

```
sudo iwconfig
```

The output will be like this:

> lo        no wireless extensions.
>
> eth0      no wireless extensions.
>
> wlan0     IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:"Network Wifi name"
>             Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.457 GHz  Access Point: 64:0F:28:1B:18:A9
>             Bit Rate=54 Mb/s   Tx-Power=15 dBm
>             Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
>             Power Management:on
>             Link Quality=70/70  Signal level=-32 dBm
>             Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
>             Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:137   Missed beacon:0

As you can see, wlan0 seems to be the WiFi interface and Power management under it is set to ON. You can fix that by disabling power management on the radio with this command:

```
sudo iwconfig wlan0 power off
```

This should fix it. If not, then its probably a driver issue. I cannot pinpoint the issue well because of the lack of information in the question.