# Network Problem with Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: 11.10, networking

I have a lot of network problems since I made the upgrade to the 11.10

In our company, We have 3 computers upgraded to the 11.10. Every one of this have network problems. The other computers are under Ubutun 11.04 ands works fine.

The network problem are not constants, sometimes after a reboot it's working. But if there are a problem I stay since a reboot. 
For example we have :

- Connection troubles : streaming music does not work more than 30s, a lot of AJAX request does not work.
- Error on requesting a webpage, the browser (firefox, chromium) doesn't find the hosts
- Error often on requesting a webpage for a /etc/hosts host
- Error on ssh or scp, display the message : no root to host
- Error on svn.

We already tried :

- Desactivate IP v6
- Install Wicd instead of "Network Manager"
- Replace the /etc/resolv.conf by static data
- etc.

Is somebody have an idea ?

Thanks a lot !

See you,
Thomas.

[Edit] Add some hard ware informations

```
sudo lspci -nn
00:00.0 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation 82P965/G965 Memory Controller Hub [8086:29a0] (rev 02)
00:01.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 82P965/G965 PCI Express Root Port [8086:29a1] (rev 02)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation 82G965 Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:29a2] (rev 02)
00:02.1 Display controller [0380]: Intel Corporation 82G965 Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:29a3] (rev 02)
00:19.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation 82562V 10/100 Network Connection [8086:104c] (rev 02)
00:1a.0 USB Controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) USB UHCI Controller #4 [8086:2834] (rev 02)
00:1a.1 USB Controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) USB UHCI Controller #5 [8086:2835] (rev 02)
00:1a.7 USB Controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) USB2 EHCI Controller #2 [8086:283a] (rev 02)
00:1b.0 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) HD Audio Controller [8086:284b] (rev 02)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) PCI Express Port 1 [8086:283f] (rev 02)
00:1d.0 USB Controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) USB UHCI Controller #1 [8086:2830] (rev 02)
00:1d.1 USB Controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) USB UHCI Controller #2 [8086:2831] (rev 02)
00:1d.2 USB Controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) USB UHCI Controller #3 [8086:2832] (rev 02)
00:1d.7 USB Controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) USB2 EHCI Controller #1 [8086:2836] (rev 02)
00:1e.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 82801 PCI Bridge [8086:244e] (rev f2)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge [0601]: Intel Corporation 82801HH (ICH8DH) LPC Interface Controller [8086:2812] (rev 02)
00:1f.2 RAID bus controller [0104]: Intel Corporation 82801 SATA RAID Controller [8086:2822] (rev 02)
00:1f.3 SMBus [0c05]: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) SMBus Controller [8086:283e] (rev 02)
```

--

```
sudo lshw -class network
  *-network               
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: 82562V 10/100 Network Connection
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 19
       bus info: pci@0000:00:19.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 02
       serial: 00:19:d1:47:e4:da
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 100Mbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=1.3.10-k2 duplex=full firmware=1.1-2 ip=192.168.2.166 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=100Mbit/s
       resources: irq:42 memory:dfde0000-dfdfffff memory:dfddb000-dfddbfff ioport:ecc0(size=32)
```

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! We need more hardware information to help you, can you look at [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into) and then edit your question adding the information?

Comment: [Try this DNS configuration](http://askubuntu.com/questions/66989/ubuntu-11-10-network-speed/72180#72180)

Comment: Thanks José for your help. but it's not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have news about our network problem.
It's seems to be an icmp-redirect bug with Linux kernel >= 3.0.0
The kernel adds entries in the ARP table from ICMP redirect message and should not.

The solution is :

1. Edit /etc/sysctl.conf to add :
   net.ipv4.conf.all.accept_redirects=0
   net.ipv4.conf.default.accept_redirects=0
2. Reboot

Answer (score 3):

It seems to be a Linux kernel bug.
We roll back to the 2.6.38 and everything is fine again.
To do that, we just [installed Grub Customizer [French link]](http://www.simounet.net/nettoyer-la-liste-de-linux-kernel-headers-de-grub-grub-customizer-ou-ligne-de-commande/)

Also it should be possible to [remove old unused Linux Kernel Headers like this [English link]](https://ubuntugenius.wordpress.com/2011/01/08/ubuntu-cleanup-how-to-remove-all-unused-linux-kernel-headers-images-and-modules/)